# import { ethers } from "ethers" vs const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

Tags: node.js, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am working on an NFTMarketplace project with the guidance of a tutorial, where I am obviously requiring "ethers.js".

In my **test.js** file (*which I run using npx hardhat test*), it is required to use **const { ethers } = require("hardhat");**. On the other hand, in the **Home.js** (*which is for react frontend*), I am required to use **import { ethers } from "ethers"**.

Now my question is, why I'm importing the same thing in 2 different ways.

Comment: The first one imported from `hardhat` and the second one imported from `ethers` (`import {ethers} from ethers` can be used instead of `require`). He is asking why we import the same thing from two different modules.

Answer (score 1):

When using hardhat you do not need to import "ethers"

> The Hardhat Runtime Environment, or HRE for short, is an object
> containing all the functionality that Hardhat exposes when running a
> task, test or script. In reality, Hardhat is the HRE.

https://hardhat.org/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment?utm_source=buildspace.so&utm_medium=buildspace_project